# Dont let user click the image too many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have this image on which I have given an onclick function which in turn calls a function which performs some animation on screen. Now if you click the image too many times too fast the animation goes on that many times even after the user has stopped clicking. I do not want that happening. I want the user be able to click next time only after the animation is over (read JQuery animate) for the previous click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either just call

```
.stop( true, true )
```

before you call any jQuery *fx* function or you can check if the target element is currently animated, like

```
if(!$( '#myimage' ).is( ':animated' ) ) {
}
```

The former solution would just "reset" the animation (parameters indicate, clear queue and jump to end). With the latter solution you could just not allow any further click(handlers) from firing.

Reference: [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/), [`:animated selector`](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/)

Answer (score 4):

You can create a boolean value, set it to false when the animation start, true when the animation is over and true by default. Allow the user to click when the boolean is set to true.

Comment: Even I had thought of the same but kind of does not feel right. Am looking for some better way.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a more object oriented preferred way (see closures), but you could do it simply like this:

```
var isInFunction = false;

function myHandler() {
    if (isInFunction) {
        return;
    }
    isInFunction = true;

    // do function logic

    isInFunction = false;
}
```

Or alternatively, if you are using a jQuery animate function, you'll want to set isInFunction back to false AFTER the animation has complete, so you should set a callback to set that var to false after the amount of time that the animation takes.

Keep in mind that this means that this variable will be the same one for ALL images, so if you want to be able to animate multiple images simultaneously, you'll have to somehow separate variables to a per-image basis.

jAndy's way is better than this because `:animated` will already do what I'm suggesting you should do, and on a per-image/element basis, but without any additional overhead/callbacks on your part!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is set any of the image tag to 1 onclick and after animation is finished set the tag back to 0.

You can implement a check animation only start when tag's value is 0